# Spring Boot microservices deployment in production

Tags: spring-boot, jboss-eap-7

In our project we are developing microservices in Spring Boot and there are over 50 microservices. Till now we were deploying them as WAR files in JBoss server, but it is frequently running Out Of Memory as we are deploying these huge number of WAR files in one server. So can anyone say me what are the other deployment alternatives I can think about? I am deploying inhouse and not on cloud.

In the standalone deployment as executable jar file, how will I be able to achieve Disaster Recovery?

Comment: As far as I know, If you deploy it as an executable jar file you can manage individual application easily ie configure individual application easily (best option is to use cloud where you can manage it easily). In case of Disaster recovery we can try with operation manager please try with below approach. https://docs.microfocus.com/OMi/10.62/Content/OMi/AdminGuide/Disaster/disaster_prep_env.htm

Answer (score -1):

To prevent failure at first - have you tried to increase heap memory space in JBoss? Default value is too small for such huge amount of apps. You can adjust this by changing the -Xms and -Xmx settings of the JBOSS_JAVA_OPTS token in site-options.conf

Comment: I changed the Java Heap space and MaxMetaSpace, but still getting OutOfMemory error intermittently.